# Forgot password does not work in magento 1.9.0.1

Tags: magento-1.9.1

Hi when customers click on "forgot Password" they receive the email with a link to reset.  When clicked this is the error that they are receiving.  Fatal error: Call to a member function setCustomerId() on a non-object in /home/ishieldz/public_html/store/app/code/core/Mage/Customer/controllers/AccountController.php on line 750
Any help would be appreciated.  Thank you!

/**
     * Display reset forgotten password form
     *
     * User is redirected on this action when he clicks on the corresponding link in password reset confirmation email
     *
     */
    public function resetPasswordAction()
    {
        $resetPasswordLinkToken = (string) $this->getRequest()->getQuery('token');
        $customerId = (int) $this->getRequest()->getQuery('id');
        try {
            $this->_validateResetPasswordLinkToken($customerId, $resetPasswordLinkToken);
            $this->loadLayout();
            // Pass received parameters to the reset forgotten password form
            $this->getLayout()->getBlock('resetPassword')
                ->setCustomerId($customerId)
                ->setResetPasswordLinkToken($resetPasswordLinkToken);
            $this->renderLayout();
        } catch (Exception $exception) {
            $this->_getSession()->addError( $this->_getHelper('customer')->__('Your password reset link has expired.'));
            $this->_redirect('*/*/forgotpassword');
        }
    }

Answer (score 1):

If you are in **Magento 1.9.1** Here is a solution which worked for me.

If your theme doesn’t include any specific custom config or layout settings you can safely **delete** your customer.xml (or just rename to customer1.xml) file located at `/app/design/frontend/default/<your_theme_package>/<your_theme_name>/layout/customer.xml`

> If you delete this file magento will load the default config options
>   (with the updates) from the factory default magento theme. 
>   /app/design/frontend/base/default/layout/customer.xml

*Remember to flush / refresh your magento config via administration area, this will force the customer.xml file to be reloaded.*

Answer (score 0):

It seems that your invoking an udeclared object, so maybe it's only a variable.
Verify if you're declaring your object before the line 750 in your AccountController.php

You must put the declaration of the object (Example: $ob = new Customer();) 
that contains the setCustomerId() method, into the method that is running.

Comment: I added the above code from the file.  This is Magento 1.9.0.1 default

Answer (score 0):

login to magento. go to system, design. Delete your current theme and then re-add again.